# Symfony 1.4: how to enable non-numerical IDs for routes in admin generator?

Tags: php, routes, symfony1, url-routing, symfony-1.4

My model is built on non-numerical ID's (36-char. GUID to be specific).

The problem is that when I run symfony 1.4 admin generator, it assumes that all my IDs are numeric and applies default routing requirements.

I tried providing specific routing requirements as advised here: http://www.codemassacre.com/2009/04/27/symfony-12-admin-with-custom-primary-key/ In my case the snippet from routing.yml is:

```
organization:
  class: sfPropelRouteCollection
  options:
    model:                Organization
    module:               account
    prefix_path:          /account
    column:               id
    with_wildcard_routes: true
  requirements:
    id: \w+
```

However, I am still getting 404 errors indicating that my route wasn't matched. The URL I am matching is "/account/8985329a-fd3b-41a0-b27b-f45c80d51765/edit". It looks like my requirement for the given route is being ignored.

I could create my routes manually but I'd rather not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because `\w` doesn't match `-` character.

So you have to replace `\w+` with, say, `[\w-]+` or `[\da-f-]+` (more strict regexp)

Answer (score 1):

`[\w-]+` did not work for me, but `'[\w-]+'` did (symfony 1.4.10).

I think symfony/php was interpreting the `[]` syntax
as an array specification.